# Create Listbox can't move like Me hub or message hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

when i open Me Hub in Windows Phone Device, i saw the Profile Pivot.

at that pivot item, i can move listBox up or down in Lanscape mode. And it can't move in Portrait mode. 
It work similar when i write node in calender.

How can i do it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a ListBox. You can "cover" your controls in the pivot in a scrolviewer. It should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Visibility of the Listboxes, internal, ScrollViewer when the orientation changes